# Add MenuItem Images In top of the imageview in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

In my Layer i have added One image view then i want to add CCMenuItem Images on top of the Image View.
How can i do this in Cocos2d

give me any suggestions

edit : moved code from comments

```
img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 480)]; 
img.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: img];
CCMenuItemImage *topBarBtn1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"TapButtonR.png" 
                                                     selectedImage:@"TapButtonR.png"             
                                                            target:self 
                                                          selector:@selector(gamePlay:)]; 
CCMenu *tapScreen = [CCMenu menuWithItems:topBarBtn1, nil]; 
tapScreen.position = ccp(160, 70); 
[self addChild:tapScreen z:2 ];
```

Comment: img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, 320, 480)];
img.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview: img];

Comment: CCMenuItemImage *topBarBtn1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"TapButtonR.png" selectedImage:@"TapButtonR.png" target:self selector:@selector(gamePlay:)];
CCMenu *tapScreen = [CCMenu menuWithItems:topBarBtn1, nil];
tapScreen.position = ccp(160, 70);
[self addChild:tapScreen z:2 ];

Comment: i want to add ccmenuiteminage top of the image view

Comment: same question as here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19677986/how-to-add-ccsprite-over-uiview

Comment: i dnt want to add ccmenuitemimage to uiview...i want add ccmenuitem to uiimageview