# How to add CCSprite over UIView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone

In my cocos2d application, I have a `UIView` that I am displaying on my screen by adding a subview to `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView]`, but I am wondering if there is someway to display a `CCSprite` above this view, since I have to do lots of interactions and animations with those CCObjects.

Please help. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can't add CCSprite on UIView. CCSprite is from Cocos2d library class and UIView is UIKit class. If you want add UIView over game view then you need to access rootviewcontroller view which is root of UIWindow. Its something like this,

```
[appDelegate.yourRootViewController.view addSubview:yourview];
```

Always keep remember Cocos2d library control are part of GLView.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible. The cocos2d view is a view and everything it contains can only be "in" this cocos2d view. Any other view is either on top of or behind the cocos2d view. Thus you can't do things like putting a view between two cocos2d nodes.

Comment: Is it possible to place a UIView behind the cocos2d view (CCSprite)? Confused, Can you please explain.

Comment: You can put a view behind everything on the cocos2d view. Which means the view will be behind ALL cocos2d nodes. For that you have to make the cocos2d view transparent (opaque = NO, bg color = clear color, 32-bit framebuffer), augmented reality apps use this to display the camera contents in the background.

Comment: @VinoyAlex dude you its doesn't possible that why LearnCocos2D give you one solution in cocos2d and me given you solution using UIKit framework. According my solution you simple bypass cocos2d CCSprite -> CCNode-> CCObject hierarchy and using UIView -> NSObject